# path name too long in tmp location of installer

Tags: inno-setup

My Installer contains some documentation crawled from a website. The resulting folder structure is quite extensive and so it now happened that a particular path and file went over the 260 character limit with the result of Innosetup complaining during the copy process from `{tmp}` that it cannot find the file.

[image]

I made sure to use UNC paths for the `Source` and `DestDir` parameters in the `[Files]` section to prevent issues during build and installation but it's failing when trying to copy from the unpacked folder in `{tmp}`.

Currently it looks like this:

```
C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\is-H7H6B.tmp\7de477cab9790185e1d8d84a307e35588102956b2cc825c1cd9a4b289cfd2505\Samples\Learn\OfflineHelp\https.docs.XXXXXXXXXXXXX\images\thumb\3\38\Setup_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_parameters.png\460px-Setup_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX_parameters.png
```

Outside of shortening the path, is there a general approach to prevent this?

If it matters: Long path names are allowed on my side in windows.

thanks!

Comment: Post [mcve] please.